# UI5 Messagebox synchron

Tags: sapui5, messagebox

Hi i implemented a Messagebox in a for loop, but i know the messagebox works asynchron. 
I want that the programm wait for every loop to the desicion of the user.

```
onBook: function(oEvent) {
  var that = this;
  for (var i = 0; i < Items.length; i++){

      function message(innerArg) {
        sap.m.MessageBox.confirm(
                "Text", {
                  icon : sap.m.MessageBox.Icon.INFORMATION,
                  title : "Really",
                  actions : [ sap.m.MessageBox.Action.YES,
                      sap.m.MessageBox.Action.NO ],
                  onClose : function(oAction) {
                    if (oAction === sap.m.MessageBox.Action.NO) {
                     delete(i);
                    }else{

                    }
                  }
                });
        }

        message(i);

  }
 that.do(oEvent);
```

The programm jumps in the "do" method before a user action is done

Edit:

```
      for (var i = 0; i < Items.length; i++){

      (function (innerArg) {
        sap.m.MessageBox.confirm(
                "Delete?", {
                  icon : sap.m.MessageBox.Icon.INFORMATION,
                  title : "Delete",
                  actions : [ sap.m.MessageBox.Action.YES,
                      sap.m.MessageBox.Action.NO ],
                  onClose : function(oAction) {
                    if (oAction === sap.m.MessageBox.Action.NO) {
                     delete(innerArg)
                  }}
                });
        })(i);   

  }
 that.Save(oEvent);
```

When the box is open the entries are booked because the programm goes to the save method without wating of user action Whats wrong ?

Comment: Your `Save` method (which is executed synchronously) does not wait for the asynchronous calls to be finished; as I mentioned before, you should use Promises (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise for more information)

Comment: Thanks, but there i can use resolve at the end of the loop and this is also asynrchon and he jumps in the save method. I have absolutly no clue how i can use it now :/ Thanks for your help !

Comment: It's just standard Javascript; use Promise.all() to catch the message box actions (so it resolves after all message boxes are closed) and perform your save in the resolve callback function

Comment: But i have only one message box open.  for java script ther eis the confirm method, is there nothing not so complicated for UI5 to intereupt the programm ? Because i do not understand the promise :/

Comment: See my updated answer. On a sidenote, I would advise to look a bit deeper into how to handle asynchronous processing using callback functions and Promises; although synchronous processing may seem easier to code, asynchronous processing has way, way more benefits. Happy coding! :)

Comment: Thanks! Now i get it and understand the promises :)

Answer (score 1):

Ah, the asynchronous-function-in-a-synchronous-loop anti-pattern ;-)

You can try using closures:

```js
for (var i = 0; i < items; i++) {
    // use self-executing function here
    (function(innerArg) {
        sap.m.MessageBox.confirm(
            "Text", {
                onClose: function(oAction) {
                    if (oAction === sap.m.MessageBox.Action.NO) {
                        // here I want to do something
                        console.log("Value: ", innerArg);                        
                    }
                }
            }
        );
    })(i);
}
```

#### EDIT: Update with Promises

Based on your updated question, I have provided a more-or-less sorta-kinda working example (it may not work flawless, but it should show the design pattern you should follow)

You wrap the message box responses into a Promise resolve, and store these into an array. You then feed that array to Promise.all() in order to proceed with your save functionality

```js
processData: function() {
    var promises = [],
        self     = this;

    for (var i = 0; i < items; i++) {
        promises.push(this.doMessageboxAction(i));
    }

    Promise.all(promises).then(function(aData) {
        aData.forEach(function(oData) {
            self.save(oData);
        });
    }).catch(function(err) {
        console.log(err);
    });
}

doMessageboxAction: function(item) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        sap.m.MessageBox.confirm(
            "Text", {
                onClose: function(oAction) {
                    if (oAction === sap.m.MessageBox.Action.NO) {
                        //do something
                        //etc
                        resolve(item); // or some other variable
                    }
                    else {
                        //do something else
                        //etc
                        resolve(item); // or some other variable
                    }
                }
            }
        );
    });
}
```

Comment: It doesn't really work, I want to delete some entries if the user push NO and after the loop i want to book the remaining entries. Do you have a hint ?

Comment: It should work; but remember, you can't use variable `i` anymore. But if you want to go back into synchronous mode by manipulating the results **after** you exit the loop, I would really, **really** advise to use Promises instead

Comment: First, you should never change the original code in your post since that makes the provided answers irrelevant -- better do an edit and add the modified code instead. Second, as I said before, **you cannot use var `i` anymore** since you now use a self-executing function which acts a s a closure. `i` is now passed via `innerArg` in my example

Comment: Ok but also with 'innerArg' the programm jumps out to the 'do' method

Comment: Yes, because your code is incorrect; have a good look at the syntax I provided : `(function(innerArg) { ..... })(i);`

Comment: I make the syntax but he jumps automatically in the save method when the box is on the screen i posted the code with an edit